# What is the order of precedence of operator in DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

Query is below

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "messi NOT barca AND psg",
          "fields": ["name^128"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the difference in `"query": "messi AND barca NOT psg"`

What is order of precedence in AND, OR, NOT in DSL

Comment: Since lucene is built in java, the order is NOT > AND > OR.

Comment: @rabbitbr any reference i can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TLDR;

As [per the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators)

> The familiar boolean operators AND, OR and NOT (also written &&, || and !) are also supported but beware that they do not honor the usual precedence rules, so parentheses should be used whenever multiple operators are used together.

Depending on what you want to need to set your parenthesis right.

## To understand

`messi NOT barca AND psg` -> will match `messi psg`

`messi AND barca NOT psg` -> will match `messi barca`

`messi NOT (barca AND psg)` -> will match `messi barca` or `messi psg` but not `messi barca psg`